# How to use std::vector in PHP using SWIG

Tags: php, c++, swig

I am working on wrapping a C++ API in PHP using SWIG. I am most of the way there but I am having problems with a function that returns a vector. The header looks something like this:

```
#include <vector>

namespace STF
{
class MyClass
{
    public:
        const std::vector<MyOtherClass> &getList();
};
}
```

The interface file looks like this:

```
%include <std_vector.i>
%import "STF_MyOtherClass.i"

%{
    #include "STF_MyOtherClass.h"
    #include "STF_MyClass.h"
%}

%include "STF_MyClass.h"
```

I seem to be able to call the function fine but it is returning a PHP resource instead of an object. Specifically it is a resource of type: "_p_std__vectorT_STF__MyClass_t".

How can I either get this to return an object that I can iterate through (preferably with a foreach loop) or how can I iterate through this resource?

**Update:**

I have been working on a solution based off of what I read here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.swig/16817

Basically I am trying to convert the vector into a python array:

```
%typemap(out) std::vector<STF::MyOtherClass>
{
    array_init( return_value );

    std::vector<STF::MyOtherClass>::iterator itr;

    itr = $1.begin();

    for( itr; itr != $1.end(); itr++ )
    {
        zval* tmp;

        MAKE_STD_ZVAL( tmp );
        SWIG_SetPointerZval( tmp, &*itr, $descriptor(STF::MyOtherClass*), 2 );

        add_next_index_zval( return_value, tmp );
    }
}
```

This is very close to working. I put a breakpoint inside the wrapper code within SWIG_ZTS_SetPointerZval. When it goes to initialize the object it does a zend_lookup_class for "stf__myotherclass" which fails (it doesn't find a clasS). I am not sure why it can't find the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end this is what I did to convert the vector into a PHP array (put this in the interface file for MyOtherClass):

```
%typemap(out) const std::vector<STF::MyOtherClass>&
{
    array_init( return_value );

    std::vector<STF::MyOtherClass>::const_iterator itr;

    itr = $1->begin();

    for( itr; itr != $1->end(); itr++ )
    {
        zval* tmp;

        STF::MyOtherClass * res = new STF::MyOtherClass( *itr );

        MAKE_STD_ZVAL( tmp );

        swig_type_info type = *$descriptor(STF::MyOtherClass*);
        type.name = (char*)"_p_CustomNamespace\\MyOtherClass";

        SWIG_SetPointerZval( tmp, res, &type, 2 );

        add_next_index_zval( return_value, tmp );
    }
}
```

The %template that awoodland did not work for me. I think it is probably because I did not put the PHP class in a different custom namespace. Instead, I did this manually and passed in the exact php class I wanted it to use.

Answer (score 7):

You're almost there, but as well as `%include <std_vector.i>` you'll also need something like:

```
%template (MyVector) std::vector<MyOtherClass>;
```

This instructs SWIG to expose vectors of `MyOtherClass` to the target language as a type called `MyVector`. Without doing this SWIG doesn't know which types you want to instantiate `std::vector` for, so it's reduced to the default wrapping.

Side note:

Is there a reason you've got the `const` in `const std::vector<MyOtherClass> getList();` when it's not a reference? I'd either make it a reference and make the method `const` also (`const std::vector<MyOtherClass>& getList() const;`) or drop the `const` entirely since it does nothing there.

Comment: tl;dr: you need to explicitly instantiate `std::vector` to expose specific types to PHP.

Comment: I tried this solution but I am still getting a resource returned to me. Maybe this is because my classes are in a namespace? (I updated the post above to add the namespace). I tried looking through the wrapper code generated and I don't see where it would be attempting to create the MyVector object. The functions exist to do it but they don't seem to be reference anywhere else. Also, the getList function was supposed to be by reference, I just mistyped it.

Comment: @drewag - You need to explicitly mention the namespace in your `%template` directive. The typemap you showed will change the behaviour to make some of the typemaps in `%include <std_vector.i>` not get applied I think. I'll try and put together a more complete example.

Comment: I tried explicitly mentioning the namespace and that still didn't work for me. I think it is probably because I put the PHP class in a different namespace than it defaults to. In the end I went with the typemap solution. Thanks for you help!